# Use one search string to search 4 website catalogs

Tags: algorithm, web-crawler

I frequent many libraries. The Brooklyn Public Libraries, Queens Public Libraries, New York Public Libraries and CUNY schools libraries. When I want a book I have to go to all 4 online catalogs and search for it. I want to instead write a program that takes the book, author, ISBN, or whatever keywords as a string and then return 4 search result as if I went to each catalog site manually. I think this would be considered a web crawler. I'm fairly good at following programming tutorials, and googling something when I know what I'm looking for. I really have no idea where to start and would appreciate some advice. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some python based scripts and examples of how you can automate the crawling/scraping of each online catalog.  This can be done in any language, but python in my opinion would be the simplest.

[Simple Web Crawler (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576551-simple-web-crawler/)

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Or, to do it without a prewritten script you would use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to get the web page source and then parse that source with something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  And with the parsed source, do some keyword checks, and display the results.

Comment: OMG thank you so much!!!!! I didn't even know there were web crawler frameworks. Idk how to use python yet but you've just inspired me, and know I know what urllib2 and BeautifulSoup are. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem @MsKhadijah.  Happy to help!  Please click the checkmark below the Up/Down Arrows to the left of the answer to accept the answer.  It will help others know that this solution is valid.  Thanks!